# What should be used 'related to' or 'related with' [cell programming]?

Tags: prepositions

Full text:

- *Furthermore, genes related with cell reprogramming are activated and play an important role during the regeneration process after damage.*

My issue: I consulted my urologist friend, he told me that in their medical books, "genes related with cell reprogramming" is mentioned. I think that the preposition "to" could be placed before cell reprogramming, but reading the sentence with "to" gives a mismatched sound and vibe to the sentence. Please help.

Comment: I'd rephrase. '... genes involved in cell reprogramming ...'.

Comment: "cell reprogramming" isn't such a common thing for genes to be involved in, compared to, say, "inflammation". So [here's the NGram for that one,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=genes+related+%2A+inflammation&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgenes%20related%20to%20inflammation%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgenes%20related%20to%20inflammation%3B%2Cc0) showing that the only preposition that occurs often enough to chart in ***genes related** [preposition] **inflammation*** is in fact ***to***.

Comment: There is one Google hit to a research paper with "genes related with cell reprogramming"  but it is by researchers from a Chinese institution who appear to be Chinese and therefore they may not be the best guides for English preposition use. Possibly Chinese uses a different preposition/postposition. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5359186/

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I was also thinking the same. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I never tried the NGram search feature. This is new to me but it was very helpful. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @StuartF I read the full article. It was a good read but there were a lot of grammatical mistakes in the article. I believe a different proposition system does exist. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I try to give you a fishing rod rather than a fish, if you understand that "idiomatic reference".